# How to handle DB.close when background thread is processing data to database?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting a

`java.lang.IllegalStateException Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.`

because my app gets info from a server and processes it in a `background thread` which writes stuff to my `SQLite database`.

I receive this error when I close the app and there is still a background thread running trying to write to a closed database.

**What is the best way for me to solve this issue?**

Comment: suspend the background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way for me to solve this issue?

Don't close the database wherever you are closing it. Either find a better time to close it (when you know nothing will need it anymore), or simply do not close it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming the system will automatically take care of closing it when all the functions are finished?

Comment: @TheNomad: Not really. The database will simply remain open until your process is terminated. This is not unusual and does not cause any particular harm. SQLite is transactional, and so everything is written to disk when you perform your actual database I/O.